# Does an air conditioner's fan use more power on Max than on Auto?

Tags: hvac, energy-efficiency, inverter

I have an inverter air conditioner unit. I usually set it on 26°C, to save energy consumption. I live in a really hot area (it's 34°C right now (~93°F), in the middle of the night). My questions is about the fan speed options. I'm using it on AUTO, but it becomes kinda hot when it slows down, and I start sweating... So, if I just set it on max speed (my unit have 5 speed adjustment) it will consume more than on AUTO?

Answer (score 3):

A faster fan will use more energy for the fan than Auto, and will technically use a little bit more energy for cooling as the fan running at a higher speed will add more heat to the room. In practical terms, assuming the equipment is working properly, you will be unlikely to notice the energy usage difference. If it helps you to be more comfortable, I say go for it.

Comment: One addition to this that is not an answer but rather a question: do you turn it on when things are already hot? Inverter units are often a bit oversized so they can throttle down and run quietly. This means if you don't turn them on until things are hot, they might not dehumidify enough to make things comfortable. If you're waiting until it's uncomfortably hot to turn the unit on, try turning it on a little bit earlier and seeing if it does a better job of controlling humidity.

Comment: agree with KMJ...also consider lowering the temperature a degree or 2. rather than change the fan speed.

Comment: I would be uncomfortably hot at 26 C (78 F) in Dallas, Texas USA. I keep our thermostat at 74 F (23 C). Our system is a traditional US system in which the air handler runs at a single speed, rather high and noisy in a/c mode and much lower and quieter during the heating season.

Comment: Multi-speed and variable-speed systems do a much better job of dehumidifying, generally, and I find I can be comfortable at higher temperatures with them because of it.

Comment: I am 79 yo and grew up in Dallas TX USA in the days before home a/c was common. We did not have home a/c in the 1950s. I can remember trying to sleep when it was 35 C (95 F) at 10 pm. A slightly noisy air handler keeping me cool is way down on my list of annoying conditions. Our 53 yo tract house has the air handler in a closet in the center of the house right off the kitchen/den where I spend my waking hours. It is a little noisy there, but not in the bedroom. The bedroom is kept at 72 F (22 C) by setting the restrictors. Eight hours of sleep at 72 F is . . . well. . . Paradise.